# Microsoft Outlook 2013 quick steps non-default font

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

How do I get Outlook 2013 quick steps to use a non-default font?  For example, Outlook is using Calibri as the default font (which is automatically used in the quick steps), but I want the font in the quick step (and only in the quick step) to use a different font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Steps are simple actions which use existing settings within Outlook to make things "quick". They are not designed for editing messages, formatting font, etc. So, you can not change the font from a Quick Step.

You may want to consider using a macro or a template formatted to your liking. I frequently use templates for recurring emails. It's quick and easy preformatted message available any time.

Comment: Hi CharlieRB,Thanks for the response.  If I were to use a Macro do you have any thoughts/suggestions on what the macro code should be as you cammot record a macro in outlook?

Comment: [Use Word Macro to Apply Formatting to Outlook Email](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/word-macro-apply-formatting-outlook-email/)

Comment: Hi CharlieRB - Many thanks for your swift response re macro Code to format selected text - it works a treat!

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel this answered your question, please select the check mark under the vote count on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I found below method on [a related Microsoft forum topic](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/quick-step-respond-new-message-font/e605520d-21d6-4141-a041-affd1ab681bc).

The answer is found in a post by [Jay Knecht](http://In%20Word,%20go%20to%20File%20%3E%20Options%20%3E%20Advanced%20%3E%20General%20(section)%20%3E%20Web%20Options%20%3E%20Fonts%20(tab)%20and%20changed%20the%20Proportional%20Font%20from%20Times%20New%20Roman%20to%20Calibri.), the essential part to change the font of the Quick Step is:

> In Word, go to File > Options > Advanced > General (section) > Web
>   Options > Fonts (tab) and changed the Proportional Font

For some reason the Quick Step uses the font set under Proportional Font in Word.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the Microsoft related forum of Jay Knight and some experimenting I found out that the font can be defined in NormalEmail.dotm (in %AppData%\Microsoft\Templates).

I editted my Normal.dotm (also in %AppData%\Microsoft\Templates) in word and saved it as NormalEmail.dotm.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I would pass this along because I have previously done this but was searching for how to do so again.
You can change the font used by quick steps emails.

See the following superuser answer
[How to change the Body font in Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/732299/how-to-change-the-body-font-in-outlook)