# Microsoft Outlook 2016: How to change default numbered and bullet list styles?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

At my company, we use Microsoft Outlook 2016.

I was able to change my **default** font face and size using this answer: [How to change the Body font in Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/732299/how-to-change-the-body-font-in-outlook/1513533#1513533)

However, I don't how to change the **default** numbered list and bullet styles.

Example numbered list:

```
1.  abc
    (ア)       def  <<< bizarrely, there is a tab before "def"
       ①    ghi
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define new bullets, numbers, and multilevel lists.

On the **Message** tab, in the **Basic** group, click the arrow next to Bulleted List Word bullet button down arrow, and then click **Define New Bullet**.

[image]

Once you customize them, you can save those settings as a style and use it again and again.

See: [Define new bullets, numbers, and multilevel lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-new-bullets-numbers-and-multilevel-lists-6c06ef65-27ad-4893-80c9-0b944cb81f5f#:%7E:text=1%20Select%20the%20text%20or%20numbered%20list%20you,size%2C%20style%2C%20and%20color%2C%20click%20...%20See%20More)